# Interfacing DSP with ADC and DAC data converters on one SPI port and one chip select

Tags: signal-processing, spi, adc, dac

I want to use one SPI port with one chip select to control ADC and DAC converters. I would connect ADC to MISO pin of DSP, DAC to MOSI pin. Is this in general possible?

Comment: It depends on the specific IC. As a universal solution, one can use single CS output with extra GPIO and external glue logic (74lvc1g19 "1-gate" decoder or similar)

Comment: My plan is to use GPIO as select signal for multiplexer, which will then decide which of converters is going to be selected.
But is it possible to have both of the devices selected at the same time, and still have no problems?
Also, digital voltage of my SPI pins of DSP are 1.8V. How difficult is it to find mux with compliant to such characteristics?

Comment: *1.* One can not give an exact answer without studying of specific ADC and DAC datasheets. IMHO, that it is beyond of stack overflow scope because it's hardware issue. *2.* 74lvc series works from 1.65V

Comment: Why you can't use a GPIO for another chip select? You see, SPI is fun because you may have almost infinite number of devices to be connected (okay, theoretically, but still).